# Accessing query string/parameter from html page

Tags: html, query-string

I have a basic html page which is having a query parameter being passed to the page.  I thought I would be able to get the value with Request.QueryString but the more reading I'm doing seems that this is only for asp applications.  My html is as follows below

```
<body>
    <object type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
        <!--This didn't work-->
        <param name="src" value="<%=Request.QueryString["path"]%>" />
        <!--Neither did this-->
        <!--<param name="src" value="<%=Request.Params["path"]%>" />-->
        <!--When it is hardcoded then my page is displaying the pdf as expected.-->
        <!--<param name="src" value="scan.pdf" />-->
    </object>
</body>
```

I am calling the page with displayPdf.htm?path=scan.pdf

I've been searching for a way to access query parameters in html without having to write a javascript solution but haven't had any luck.  I'm sure adding a js function wouldn't be too big a deal just thought I would avoid it if there was a single line approach.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This cannot be done in pure HTML.

This can be done in two ways, using JavaScript:

```
<body><script>
var param = /[&?]path=([^&]+)/.exec(location.search);
param = param ? param[1].replace(/"/g, '&quot;') : '';
document.write('<object type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">\n' +
    '<param name="src" value="' + param + '" />\n</object>');
</script></body>
```

An alternative method is populating the parameter using DOM (**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N2GUf/2/**):

```
<body><object type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="src" value="" id="param-path" />
</object>
<script>
var param = /[&?]path=([^&]+)/.exec(location.search);
if (param)
    document.getElementById('param-path').value = param[1];
</script>​</body>
```

In either case, the query string is read from the [`location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location#Properties) property, and parsed using a simple regular expression.

Comment: The second style almost works for me but the javascript block is getting called before the object exists.  If I could call it after then this solution would certainly work for me.  This first did work without any changes though.  Thanks alot.